# Matlab: animating an added line to an image

Tags: matlab, animation, line, movie

i am succeeding in adding a horizontal line to an image. i want the line to begin moving downward, while erasing the previous line. and finally i want to save this movie to avi format

here is my code

```
A=imread('IMG_0628.JPG');
B=A(:,:,2);
for k=1:50:801
imshow(B), hold on
plot([1,597],[k,k])
N(k)=getframe
end
```

upon the display of the animation i am getting in the command windows the following

```
N = 

   cdata: [400x299x3 uint8]
colormap: []


N = 

1x51 struct array with fields:
cdata
colormap


N = 

1x101 struct array with fields:
cdata
colormap


N = 

1x151 struct array with fields:
cdata
colormap
```

While trying to run the movie by the `movie(N)` command i get the following error

```
??? Error using ==> movie
Movie contains uninitialized frames
```

Is there a better way to enchance my code and achieve my animation

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Get the handle back when you plot the line, then delete the handle after the getframe, and make sure the frames of the movie are sequentially numbered (right now you have one non-empty frame every 50 frames):

```
  A=imread('IMG_0628.JPG');
  B=A(:,:,2);
  imshow(B); hold on;
  counter = 1;
  for k=1:50:801
      linehandle = plot([1,597],[k,k]);
      N(counter)=getframe;
      counter = counter + 1;
      delete(linehandle);
  end
```